# The product of a normal variable by the cossine of another normal variable is a Laplace distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Let $Z=X \cos(Y)$ be a random variable where $X\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma_1)$, $Y\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma_2)$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.My goal it to obtain the PDF of Z or at least prove some behaviors.

My first approach was to evaluate the pdf of $\cos (Y)$ and after that, use the convolution theorem to get $Z$. However, I think that it's not a good way because the pdf of $\cos (Y)$ is a mess][1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35260/resultant-probability-distribution-when-taking-the-cosine-of-gaussian-distribute).

After lost time with this approach, I investigated pdf of $Z$ numerically.

[[image: See the figure here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt3dj.png)]

This distribution resembles a Laplace (exponential) distribution!

Because of the exponential decay behavior (figure), I tried to discover the characteristic function of  $Z$. The reason to do that, it’s because if the characteristic function of $Z$ coincides with the characteristic function of the Laplace distribution then I solve my problem.

I obtained the following integral for the characteristic function of $Z$,
$$
\varphi_Z(t) = 
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2}
  \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty
    \exp\left(-\frac{(t \sigma_1 \cos(y))^2}{2}\right) \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\right) 
  \mathrm{d} y,
$$
I tried to solve that integral expanding the first exponential.

$$
\varphi_Z(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \left(\frac{\sigma_1 t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2n}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} \exp(-2\sigma_2^2(n-k)^2).
$$
However, I don’t know if I’m doing something wrong. This equation doesn’t look useful.

My questions are

Is there another way to calculate the pdf of $Z$?

How to prove the exponential decaying behavior of pdf $Z$ without knowing the pdf of $Z$?